# Parallax: activate scroll of section's content only when section is at the top of viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax, skrollr

I have several sections, every section has a background image and some content (text, image etc). I'm having problems figuring out how to scroll section's content only when a particular section element is on the top of the viewport. Example can be seen here https://medium.com/@ivadenis/df823bf45a05.

Those who can't login to medium, here is the recording of effect:
http://screencast.com/t/jkQBOzlgwft

Could you point me in a right direction? Here is what I got so far...

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
}
main#content-container {
  height: 100%;
}

section.content-block {
  height:100%;
}
section > div > .inner-content {
    position:relative;
    padding-top: 90vh;
    color: white;
    height:100%;
}
section > div.background {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100% !important;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover !important;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<main>
        <section class="content-block" id="section1">
          <div class="background" style="background: url(http://placekitten.com/2000/3000?image=3);" data-center="background-position: 50% 0px;" data-top-bottom="background-position: 50% -100px;" data-anchor-target=".inner-content">
            <div class="inner-content container" >
              <div class="row">
                ... large content
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section class="content-block" id="section2">
          <div class="background" style="background: url(http://placekitten.com/2000/3000?image=3);" data-center="background-position: 50% 0px;" data-top-bottom="background-position: 50% -100px;" data-anchor-target=".inner-content">
            <div class="inner-content container" >
              <div class="row">
                ... large content
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </section>
</main>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ivadenis/VNLc8/1/

Comment: The medium link asks me to sign up

Comment: This sounds like a nightmare from a UX point of view. Having two nested scrollable elements and changing the way the scroll while you scroll.

Comment: @Prinzhorn here is the link to example http://screencast.com/t/jkQBOzlgwft. Take a look please!

Comment: It only looks like what you describe, but simply spoken they're just fixing the background at some point and then un-fix it again.

Comment: @Prinzhorn, may be. The background is parallaxed relatively to the content scroll. Also, the scroll is only possible when the section is either at the top of the view port or at the bottom. I've been looking at your 'pausing' example, but having hard time understanding the concept. Can something like this be achieved with pausing?

Comment: The "pausing" example is nothing more than taking full control over scrolling. Everything is positioned fixed and controlled by skrollr. This way you can do what you want without relying on the native scrolling behavior. From the top of my head it's probably not that easy to replicate the effect you want though.